# Hamburger icon is not visible on my homepage

Tags: navbar, hamburger-menu

I am trying to get a visible hamburger icon appear on a homepage's navbar.  So far it is transparent.  The code is below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbarcolor navbar-faded">
```

Home
        
          Page 1

Page 1-1

Page 1-2

Page 1-3

Page 2

Page 3

Sign Up

Login

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What library you are using ??

Comment: Hi there i am using bootstrap......the code is here https://jsbin.com/foluhedeki/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following to your css

```
.icon-bar {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mukesh.  It's working now...I can see hamburger icon.  Much appreciated.